# Can I have a comment between an object and a method call on separate lines?

Tags: ruby

I have a function where I'm calling an object method on a new line:

```ruby
def fn(str)
  str.gsub('a', 'a1')
     .gsub('b', 'b2')
end
```

All of this is fine and dandy... until I want to put a comment before the newline method call.

```ruby
def fn(str)
  # Replace 'a' with 'a1'
  str.gsub('a', 'a1')
     # Replace 'b' with 'b2'
     .gsub('b', 'b2')
end
```

Boom! Error.

```
SyntaxError: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
    .gsub('b', 'b2')
         ^
```

And yet, if I put the comments on the same line, the error goes away...

```ruby
def fn(str)
  str.gsub('a', 'a1')  # Replace 'a' with 'a1'
     .gsub('b', 'b2')  # Replace 'b' with 'b2'
end
```

What on earth is going on here? I'm using Ruby version  `ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin15])`.

### Edit

The Ruby parser may be getting confused about where to consider the end of the statement. `str.gsub('a', 'a1')` could be a statement on its own, or it could be continued on the next line.

Coming from the Python world, the way to get around that is to open a scope with parentheses to let the parser know:

```python
def fn(str):
  return (
    # Replace 'a' with 'a1'
    str.replace('a', 'a1')
       # Replace 'b' with 'b2'
       .replace('b', 'b2')
  )
```

Python has no problem with the above input, but Ruby still throws the same error even with the parentheses clearly bounding the statement.

Comment: `str.tr("ab" ,  "12" )`

Comment: @steenslag that's cheating ;) I'll update my example with something which can't work with `tr`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you put the period of the method call at the end of the first line instead of the beginning of the next, Ruby knows you're going to call a method eventually and is happy to let you comment meanwhile:

```
def fn(str)
  # Replace 'a' with 'a1'
  str.gsub('a', 'a1').
    # Replace 'b' with 'b2'
    gsub('b', 'b2')
end
```

I also find this easier to read, since the period at the end of the line tells *me* that the expression isn't finished yet. Besides, I put every other binary operator at the end of the line rather than at the beginning of the next (for the same reason); why make an exception for `.`? (I know it's not an operator, but it's punctuation between two identifiers, so it might as well be one as far as formatting is concerned.)

Comment: That works. The only drawback to putting `.` at the end than at the beginning is that it's less clear... hence why in the JavaScript world where this (method chaining) is very common, they put `.` at the beginning.

Comment: It always seems clear enough to me, partly because what else would indentation after something other than a conditional, and not followed by an end, mean and partly because the thing at the beginning of a continued line is often something that would not otherwise be at the beginning of the line. Note that if it's just the alignment that bugs you you can hit return after the first `.` too.

Comment: mksios, whether putting the period at the end rather the beginning is less clear (I personally don't find it so) is a criticism of the implementation of that aspect of Ruby. The point is you have no choice if you want to have a comment on a separate line between the expressions that are to be chained. Incidentally, though probably obvious, you can have any number of comment lines following `str.gsub('a', 'a1').` and/or a block of comments surrounded by `=begin` and `=end`.

Answer (score 2):

If you put a blank line between the first and the second `gsub`, Ruby does not interpret them as methods for the same object, and you will get a syntax error.

```
"hello".gsub('e','a')

       .gsub('l','w')
```

Even in this case, where I do not use any comments, this still throws the error.

> syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting end-of-input

Comment: Thanks for the example @davidhu2000. It makes sense from an ambiguity perspective that the parser is stopping the statement on line 1. What I don't get, though, it why it still doesn't work if I enclose the whole block in parentheses. The whole point is to tell the parser to keep parsing this statement until it finds the outermost `)`...

Answer (score 2):

Well, I guess there's always backslashes...

```ruby
# This works

def fn(str)
  # Replace 'a' with 'a1'
  str.gsub('a', 'a1') \
     # Replace 'b' with 'b2'
     .gsub('b', 'b2')
end
```

This is an alternative to moving the `.`'s to the end of the line as proposed by Dave Schweisguth.

Comment: I used to use \ more, but it's a bit less convenient when breaking and rejoining lines (as an expression gets longer or shorter) than a method which just uses whitespace (which my editor mostly adjusts for me).

Comment: Ruby isn't Bash, so putting in backslashes is really a last-resort thing.

Answer (score 1):

@mksios

Please make changes in your code

```
def fn(str)
    # Replace 'a' with '1' & Replace 'b' with '2'
    str.gsub('a', '1')
    .gsub('b', '2')
end
```

You are giving gsub for changing b in the next line, When you don't use comment then it consider it as a function but when you add comment above .gsub('b', '2') it breakdowns the syntax.

Comment: that's cheating ;) In my actual code I have five lines' worth of replacements and I don't want to put one ginormous comment at the start of the block.

Comment: There's no need to address the answer to the person asking the question. That's done automatically.